# Magento category/subcategory as a page

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, categories, categorization

I'm trying to use a category and its subcategory to render a custom page. To do this I've tried the following:

```
* Catalog->Categories->Manage Categories
* Create the category
      o Create any of the subcategories I want 
* Select a subcategory and select the 'Custom Design' tab
      o Select 'Custom Design' in the dropdown.
```

Now I go into my code base and do the following:

```
$: cd /var/www/host/app/design/frontend/siteredesign
$: tree custom_design/
custom_design/
├── etc
├── layout
├── locale
└── template
   └── catalog
       └── category
           └── view.phtml
```

And when I goto: host.com/category/subcategory I get a 404...what am I missing? TIA.

I would expect that view.phtml gets run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved -

Had to recreate the category and subcategory, now it all works. Go figure, Magento FTW.